# Load text into div using jQuery when the div was created by jQuery's .load() function

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm currently making a website that is able to load a template for it to use as the  way it looks, as well as load a "post" document that contains text that will be placed in the post div. However I have run into a minor snag.

It would appear that jQuery cannot see the div that it created using the .load function

I need a work around to load text into a div when the div was created by jQuery's .load() function.

HTML Code

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <script>
        $( "#header" ).load( "/Templates/Template.html #header" );
        $( "#post" ).load( "/post.html" );
    </script>
</body>
```

Template.html Code

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="post">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Post.html Code

```
<p>This is the text that will be displayed in the post</p>
```

How would I go about making jQuery see the div with "post" as the id.
PHP is an option if that would be easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a *on load complete* function since ajax is async and those two `.load()` run at the same time, so the div `#post` does not exist yet when you call it.

Try this:

```
    $("#header").load("/Templates/Template.html #header", function () {
        $("#post").load("/post.html");
    });
```

And be sure there is a `#post` inside `#header` comming from the `Template.html`  since you are replacing that divs content.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to jQuery so I didn't realise it was async